# Is there a way to make this code cleaner?

Tags: javascript, arguments, arrow-functions

So there have been a lot of instances where I have to declare callback functions for frameworks and libraries that have repetitive arguments, is there any way to declare them without repeating the arguments again and again and again...

Example:

```
(parent, args, ctx, info) => users.find((user) => user.id === parent.author)

(parent, args, ctx, info) => posts.filter((post) => post.author === parent.id) 

(parent, args, ctx, info) => /**an other different function**/
```

.
.
.

I don't know if its plausible but it would be VERY useful if we could make something like this:

```
let args = (parent, args, ctx, info)

(args) => users.find((user) => user.id === parent.author) 

(args) => posts.filter((post) => post.author === parent.id) 

(args) => /**an other different function**/
```

Comment: would using an object work? for instance `parent, arg, ctx` could be a class or object   so all you'll pass in is `(objWithProps) => objWithProps.users.find((user) => user.id === objWithProps.parent.author)`

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, you don't have to declare parameters you are not using, so you can simply do:

```
(parent) => users.find((user) => user.id === parent.author)
```